# How do I code Scalable Vector Graphics (SVG) output with SAS Enterprise Guide 6.1?

Tags: sas, enterprise-guide

The title says it all. I have used the OUTPUTFMT=SVG in the ODS GRAPHICS statement without any problems in Base SAS, but this methods seems not to be appropriate for SAS Enterprise Guide.

Comment: Need a tiny bit of information, like, what code are you running?  And is this using local server, or an actual server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look in the log you will see the issue:

```
27         ods graphics on / OUTPUTFMT=SVG;
28         
29         proc reg data=test;
30         model y=x;
31         run;

WARNING: SASREPORT13 destination does not support SVG images. Using the default static format.
```

So it is the default output type that EG produces that is the problem.  You can see that in the log as well:

```
15         ODS tagsets.sasreport13(ID=EGSR) FILE=EGSR
16             STYLE=HtmlBlue
17             STYLESHEET=(URL="file:///C:/Program%20Files/SASHome/SASEnterpriseGuide/7.1/Styles/HtmlBlue.css")
18             NOGTITLE
19             NOGFOOTNOTE
20             GPATH=&sasworklocation
21             ENCODING=UTF8
22             options(rolap="on")
23         ;
```

Got to Tools->Options.  In the window select "Results General" and change to HTML as your results format.

Now when you run the code, you get HTML and SVG files produced.  They will be in the `GPATH` location defined.

It does not look like the SAS HTML viewer is capable of displaying the SVG files.  You will have to download them yourself and look at them.

NOTE: I'm using EG 7.1, but the file menu choices should be very similar.

Comment: I imagine SVG viewer uses IE internally, which prior to I think version 9? or 10? couldn't display SVG.  I would think you could change that, presumably by using the Viewer option.

Comment: I have mine set to Chrome.  I think the problem is the SVG files are put into the HTML with static links to their location on the server.  You are viewing locally and Chrome/IE/Whatever cannot get to them.

Comment: Hmm, actually I do too, and still can't see it.  And that's with Local Server.

Comment: If I switch to Local, I get a button that says results will be displayed externally to EG.  Clicking that opens the HTML in Chrome (Windows default) and I see the SVG images.

Comment: Switching: 1) HTML on  +  2) "SAS Report" result format off did the trick. Working perfect now, thank you very much for your help.

Comment: There was a post on SAS communities recently that showed how to embed the image directly into an HTML5 pages so the reference issue disappears.